# GCC equivalent to /INCLUDE Visual Studio option

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

In Visual Studio I can get specific symbols exported from a dll using [/INCLUDE (Force Symbol References)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Linker option. Is there an equivalent option in GCC?

I'm compiling with -fvisibility=hidden so no symbol is exported by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While symbols visibility might work, it is not quite the answer to the question asked. It is not a linker option, and requires source modifications, which might be undesirable. More or less equivalent is export map, but it is only available for GCC with GNU linker. GCC command-line option would be

```
 -Wl,--version-script=a.map
```

with a.map looks like

```
 {
     global: a;
     local: *;
 }
```

more info at http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use `__attribute__`:

```
void foo() __attribute__((visibility("default")));

void foo() {
  /* Implementation */
}
```

This should override your `-fvisibility=hidden` parameter for this function only. You can also do this:

```
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) my_class {
  public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();

    // Other declarations...
};
```

This exports the entire class and all declaration contained therein.